# Doctrine orderBy with PostgreSQL json column (could not identify an equality operator for type json)

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm

I have two entities Export and ExportItem. One of the columns in Export entity is `config` type json (that is only column with json type in my database).

Part of Export entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json", nullable=true)
 */
protected $config;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection|ExportItem[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\ExportItem", mappedBy="export", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 */
protected $items;
```

Part of ExportItem entity:

```
/**
 * @var Export
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Export", inversedBy="items")
 */
protected $export;
```

I want to order Exports per number of attached ExportItems, but next query throw me error "**could not identify an equality operator for type json**"

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('o')
     ->join('o.suit', 's')
     ->where('s.id = :suitId')
     ->setParameter('suitId', $suit->getId())         
     ->select('COUNT(i) AS HIDDEN nbrItems', 'o.id')
     ->leftJoin('o.items', 'i')
     ->orderBy('nbrItems', $orderDir)
     ->groupBy('o');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Just need to add

```
->groupBy('o.id');
```

in the query